Proof of the Minimality of $λ(n)$ in Carmichael's Theorem
I am currently studying Carmichael's Theorem and am particularly interested in understanding the minimality of the function $λ(n)$, where $λ(n)$ is the Carmichael function that gives the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m\equiv 1\pmod n$ for all integers $a$ that are coprime to $n$.
I would like to specifically consider the case where $n$ is a power of a prime. Could anyone provide a clear and detailed proof or explanation showing why $λ(n)$ is the smallest such number for all $n$, taking this into account? I would like to understand the proof using Euler's Theorem if possible, but the explanation should remain within the scope of high school-level mathematics, without requiring advanced concepts beyond this.
Thank you!

Any such proof would be a duplicate of many prior answers, but it is not clear which answers we should link since it is not clear what is too "advanced" to you. Please describe the proof you are reading, and where and why you have difficulty understanding it.

In my mind this is the very definition, the exponent of the multiplicative group modulo $n.$  Maybe you can expand on what alternative definition you have.
